# Unable to get slider value in Jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi i am facing hard time getting the slider value, i have five sliders in a page, i am doing it as below to get the value

```
<div>
     <label for="slider" >1. choose a value.</label>
     <input type="range" id="p1slider1" name="p1slider1" class="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5" data-highlight="true" />
     <label class="sliderlabel"></label>
    </div>
```

**Try1**

```
 var slider1 = $('input:text[id=p1slide1]').val();
  alert(slider1);
```

**Try2**

```
<script>
 $("#p1slider1").on("change", function (event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log("Slider is moving, it's value is now: " + value);
});
</script>
```

**Try 3**  tryed surrounding with div element and as below

```
$("#div-slider").change(function() {
  var slider_value = $("#p1slider1").val();
  // do something..
});
```

none of them is working for me, not sure where i am doing wrong

Also as i have five sliders and a submit button in each page, i want to send the values of all sliders into database on submit button click, what is the best way to implement it?
Any information regarding this is appreciated

**Edit**

```
 var slide1;

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#custom-li").click(insertRecordp1);
    $("#p1next").click(insertRecordp2);  // Register Event Listener when button click.

function insertRecordp1(tx) // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..
{
     var orgname = $('input:text[id=name]').val();
     alert(orgname);
}    

   function insertRecordp2(tx) // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..
{

} 
// below code not working-->your code
$("input#p1slider1").on("change", function (event) {
    slide1 = $(this).val();
    alert(slide1);
});

//below code works
$(document).on('change', function(){ 
   slider1 = $('input#p1slider1').val();
     console.log(slider1);
});


}); 
 </script>
```

is it correct way of doing can i use **slide1** in function2?

Comment: you shouldn't be use `.ready()` in jQM.

Comment: @Omar   i shouldn't use .ready()?? i want t o do some database operations how can i do it, can u please link to me good example.

Comment: @Omar on click of a button i need to collect all slider values into database, can u please tell proper flow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/t3SMa/

Comment: @Omar hi..so you mean to say all the data collecting operations  should be done in $(document).on("pagecreate", function () method?

Comment: `pagecreate` is used to bind events, depending on page's id. `.ready()` fires once per document.

Answer (score 1):

In try 1, the code below works for me.

```
  var slider1 = $('input#p1slider1').val();
  alert(slider1);
```

So just call this when you need the value.

Demo 1 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn9H7/).

In try 2, use the code (the $(this) means $("input#p1slider1")):

```
$("input#p1slider1").on("change", function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Demo 2 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5927s/).

Comment: @Carsong its not working in mobile do i have to do this on pagecreate

Comment: @teekib put it in `$( document ).ready()`. E.g.
`$( document ).ready(function() {
someFunction();
anotherFunction();
});`

Comment: hi one last question , i want to put this vales into database when i click on submit button then how i get this vales?

Comment: @teekib I assume you want a submit button and when user clicks on it, get the slider value and save it using your own method.
`$("#btn").click(function(){
var value = $("input#p1slider1").val();
save(value); //your save method
});`
Am I answering your question?

Comment: If you just need your slider value when the button is clicked,
`function insertRecordp2(tx) // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..
{
var sliderValue = $('input#p1slider1').val();
alert(sliderValue);
} `

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Var value = $('plslider1').val();
    Test(value);
    // transfer the value to the function 
});
Function Test(value) {
    Alert(value);
    // alerts the value from the slider
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('change', '#p1slider1', function(){ 
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Working Example http://jsbin.com/xakifequ/6/edit

Comment: hi you code works , but how can i store this in a variable also i have 5 sliders in a page..can u please let me know?